# How get btc address from public key in node js

Tags: node.js, cryptography, bitcoin

*I apologize for my English!*

How decode hex public key from BTC signature script to string address in node js?

For example I have the follow hex public key:

`03745AAAF364030720B2D14DE50A3310EEF521C91E36353DCA20813713535C005A`

after decoding I should get corresponding bitcoin address as

`1GNXpcYzasmmXvM4rNgkvZ5SzXgL4L9Ch6`

In https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/71867/decoding-scriptsig was question about decoding ScriptSig of btc transactions and there was the follow fragment:

```
...
21: OP_DATA_0x21:        compressed pub key (33 Bytes)
    03745AAAF3640307:20B2D14DE50A3310:EEF521C91E36353D:CA20813713535C00:5A
    This is MultiSig's compressed Public Key (X9.63 form)
    corresponding bitcoin address is:    1GNXpcYzasmmXvM4rNgkvZ5SzXgL4L9Ch6
...
```

In accordance with this question btc public key is encoded in ANSI X9.63 format.

**Do nodejs have ways to decode ANSI X9.63 format?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. For it can use bitcoinjs-lib and payments module:

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

const pubKey = "03745AAAF364030720B2D14DE50A3310EEF521C91E36353DCA20813713535C005A";

const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: new Buffer(pubKey, 'hex') });

console.log(address); //1GNXpcYzasmmXvM4rNgkvZ5SzXgL4L9Ch6
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have node and npm downloaded on your computer.

npm install bitcoinjs-lib

Download bitcoinjs library from your node terminal.

```
var bitcoin = require("bitcoinjs-lib")
```

Require bitcoinjs-lib.

```
var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom(); or var keyPair = "03745AAAF364030720B2D14DE50A3310EEF521C91E36353DCA20813713535C005A"
```

Make variable for keyPair.

```
console.log(keyPair.getAddress());
```

Test address by logging address to console. A valid bitcoin address should be returned.

```
var address = keyPair.getAddress();
```

Save bitcoin address result to a variable.

```
console.log(keyPair.toWif());
```

Test private key by logging to console. A valid bitcoin private key should be returned.

```
var pkey = keyPair.toWIF();
```

Save bitcoin private key result to a variable.